# <<airflow.providers.jdbc>> module named error in Airflow2.x

Tags: docker, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am using airflow 2.0. I am trying to connect to redshift, using docker container on mac.

Here is my dag.py:

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime,timedelta


from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator,BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.providers.jdbc.hooks.jdbc import JdbcHook



#Creating JDBC connection using Conn ID
JdbcConn = JdbcHook(jdbc_conn_id='Redshift_conn')
def getconnection():
    JdbcConn.get_connection('Redshift')
    print("connected")

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

with DAG(
    dag_id="redshift",default_args=default_args ,schedule_interval="@daily",
    catchup=False) as dag:

    t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='getconnection',
    python_callable=getconnection
)
```

Here is definition of connection
[image]

Airflow UI is showing this error and I don't know how to get rid of it.

> Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/redshift.py] Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File "", line 219, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "/opt/airflow/dags/redshift.py", line 7, in 
> from airflow.providers.jdbc.hooks.jdbc import JdbcHook ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.jdbc'

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

In Airflow 2.0, all features that are not part of the Airflow's core scheduling system were moved to separate Python packages. Airflow calls them [provider packages](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers/index.html).

JDBC functionality is provided by the [`apache-airflow-providers-jdbc` provider package.](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-jdbc/stable/index.html) Based on the error message, it looks like this package is not installed on your system. One of the ways of installing this package is

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-jdbc
```

Comment: Thenks Sergi, but it doesn't work. I am using airflow2.x. I am following the example in here https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/connect-to-redshift-salesforce-and-others-from-apache-airflow, I changed the hook part to be  "from airflow.providers.jdbc.hooks.jdbc import JdbcHook", and get_connection as "get_conn", and doesn't work even with installing the module in my docker (https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/airflow). It's returning me the same error.